# Template type constraint and empty interfaces

Tags: c#, generics, interface

I have a generic class:

```
public class Temp<T, U>
{

}
```

And I want to apply type constraints on T, U. The problem is: types which I want to use as arguments (actually, interfaces IFoo1, IFoo2, IFoo3, IFoo4) have nothing in common. I could create some base interface IFoo and apply a constraint:

```
public class Temp<T, U> where T : IFoo
{

}
```

But it's said that this is bad to have an empty interface. Do you have any suggestions on how to make constraints in a proper way?

Comment: Why you can't make two constraints for each type?

Comment: If the two interfaces have nothing in common, how can it possibly be appropriate to constrain something to those two interfaces? More (and less abstract) information is needed to answer this question properly because it sounds to me like you're going at this all wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to do this is to declare two classes:

```
public class Temp<T, U> where T : IFoo1
 {

 }

public class Temp<T, U> where T : IFoo2
 {

 }
```

But I think you would be better off with a base interface (which isn't really bad, I've never heard this before. Empty 'marker interfaces' are not so uncommon...)

Comment: Agree, empty interfaces also used in .Net, like IRequiresSessionState, so there is no anything bad to use them